# Converting Date to integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating dashboard, and i have this code which works on Vertica and MS SQL, but not with PosgreSQL.

```
INT([Order Date]) % 5 + 1
```

As result i must have a list:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

How to do that?

Comment: How does it "not work" on postgresql? do you get an error or unexpected output?

Comment: What does this result mean? You want to put consecutive dates in five different buckets? Does it matter which date gets into which bucket?

Comment: That SQL does not product that result. Please post the input data, a full query, what you are seeing , and what you want to see

Answer (score 1):

in pgsql at the variable end use `::"type"`

```
SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')::integer
```

Comment: This won't produce correct results when changing month.

Answer (score 0):

Use Julian Dates.

For example:

```
select current_date, extract(julian from current_date) % 5 + 1
```

Result:

```
current_date  ?column?
------------  --------
2022-07-07           4
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d648a31e2f1d56a03d622a06aeb6b56).